# Mirror rows on another Tab based on date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am building a sheet to keep track of daily service events. We have a main log that contains all entries, and then individual tabs for each day of the week. I am trying to get the daily tabs to automatically pull the rows from the main log.

Here's what I have. The problem is that the formula that follows is returning rows that do not match the value of `B1`.

```
=QUERY('Freewire Log Template'!A3:O, "Select * where J contains '"&B$1&"'",1)
```

I also tried the following formula using INDEX and MATCH, but it is returning duplicate rows.

```
=INDEX('Freewire Log Template'!A3:O$22, MATCH(B$1,{'Freewire Log Template'!J3:J$22},0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Was actually able to do this with the `FILTER` function

```
=FILTER('Freewire Log Template'!A3:O,'Freewire Log Template'!J3:J=B1)
```

`B1` is the date, `J3:J` is the column that I want to check for that date. `A3:O` are the rows that are mirrored.